# Where can i find the datasheet for this component (RF2001)?

Tags: rf, datasheet

Where can I find the datasheet for this component (RF2001)?

[image]

Comment: Is that a GPS receiver? It seems to rings a bell as being an obsolete GPS processor. If so GPS chipset docs can be hard to obtain without an NDA and/or being a development partner.

Comment: No, it is a part of GSM madule of K310i mobilephone.

Comment: [Maybe, you can download the GSM datasheet from this ad.](http://cgi.ebay.de/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=221131757729&ssPageName=STRK:MESE:IT) Hope the information may be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: thanks, but it's not be helpful.

Comment: God, just out of kindness to show u some references. Maybe, I should had kept silent. THANK YOU FOR YOUR REMINDING.

Comment: Oh, please guys, don't callet! also, i searched for it but i couldn't find. seems, chip's company don't like nobody know about it's chip.

Comment: who can wiki for me this question?

Comment: @Sue2013, of course help is welcome here but please be careful when posting answers of really address the problem with complete, pertinent and accurate information. In this case the link you provided doesn't really help tango-tango answering his question.

Comment: IMHO either this is a duplicate of http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/14202/2191 or @PeterJ's comment should be converted into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is a Power amplifier by Ericsson or Variously Sony-Ericsson.

St-Ericsson, Ericcson semiconductor do not carry the datasheets.  I suspect that it might have been an internal part that was never sold to the public.